# Issues with head command

Tags: head

I am trying to get the top 20 lines of `ldconfig -p` and piping them to a .txt file. I am doing the below syntax:

```
head -n 20 ldconfig -p > ex4-2-4a.txt
```

I am getting an error for invalid option for the -p. I can run `ldconfig -p > textfile.txt` and get an output, but the minute I put in the head it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Russ, did the answer below solve your problem? If so, please click the checkmark. Otherwise, let us know what went wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`head` wants a text file or input to work with, not a command. Use:

```
ldconfig -p | head -n 20 > ex4-2-4a.txt
```